# Visual Studio 2017 Ionic Cordova Empty Page When Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to Cordova and Ionic. I just finished installing the Ionic 2 template for Visual Studio 2017. When I run the debugger, it shows only an empty screen.

There is something in the console log:

> "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds."
>
> "Channel not fired:onCordovaInfoReady"

How can I fix this?

I install the template from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.Ionic2TemplatesforVisualStudio2017)

---

### NOTE

Because there is a problem with the @ionic/app-script.js, I ran this command:

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

and upgraded the `app-script.js` into version 3.2.4.

Is the error related to this? Because, the template was using app-script version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fix it. If you right click the debugging page then inspect it (Chrome inspector). There is error in the `main.js`.

Place:

```
<script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
```

before

```
<script src="build/main.js"></script>
```

in the `src/index.html` not in the `www/index.html` because the `www/index.html` will get overriden on build.